# In chapter minitoc, how do I increase the distance between the top rule and the listing of the first entry?

Tags: tocloft, minitoc

This is what my minitoc looks like: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wxr92dab4eccwis/mintoc.png. I would like to increase the distance between the top rule and the first entry to be the same as the distance between the last entry and the bottom rule.

I call `minitoc` and `tocloft` as follows:

```
\usepackage[nohints]{minitoc}
\dominitoc
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LIST OF FIGURES/TABLES
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\makeatother
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\normalfont\cftdotfill{\cftsecdotsep}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
\cftpagenumbersoff{subsection}
\cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{2em}
\cftsetindents{section}{0.7em}{3em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{2.3em}{4.2em}
```

It's a complicated preamble (hence no reprex), and I may have inadvertently changed a setting somewhere. Is there a parameter I can set to correct this?